# Javascript not saving all images at once

Tags: javascript

So, this is my problem. I am trying to save all the images in the local drive from Javascript and the code that does that looks like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    console.log(" IN ON LOAD FUNCTION ")
    for (filename=1; filename<=80; filename++)
    {
        console.log(filename)
        html2canvas(document.querySelector(`.lead${filename}`)).then(canvas => {
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
                saveAs(blob, `${filename}.png`);
                    });
            });
    }
}
```

So the code is quite clear. I have about 80 divs with different class name and I am extracting the text from it and saving it as canvas and downloading that  canvas as png format, but the problem is sometimes it downloads about 10 images, and sometimes it doesn't download at all. Any help regarding this issue? Any other way around?

Comment: We can't possibly help you without the code for `saveAs`, other than: I'm not surprised at all if the browser rate-limits triggering downloads.

Comment: Any other way around?

Comment: `saveAs` should be the exported function of the `file-saver` library, if I don't get wrong. By the way I agree with @T.J.Crowder, it should be a browser limit

Comment: A solution? You can ask the user to click every single file in order to download them, or you can zip all your images if they're supposed to go together

Comment: Just as a quick idea, you might want to try gathering your blobs in an array (or some more elaborate buffer construct) and saving them sequentially/at timed offsets to avoid the possible rate limit.